# Perl: Help writing a regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a common regular expression for the below 3 cases:

- Supernatural_S07E23_720p_HDTV_X264-DIMENSION.mkv
- the.listener.313.480p.hdtv.x264-2hd.mkv
- How.I.met.your.mother.s02e07.hdtv.x264-xor.avi

Now my regular exoression should remove the series name from the original string i,e the output of above string will be:

- S07E23_720p_HDTV_X264-DIMENSION.mkv
- 313.480p.hdtv.x264-2hd.mkv
- s02e07.hdtv.x264-xor.avi

Now for the basic case of `supernatural string` I wrote the below regex and it worked fine but as soon as the series name got multiple words it fails.

```
$string =~ s/^(.*?)[\.\_\- ]//i; #delimiter can be (. - _ )
```

So, I have no idea how to proceed for the aboves cases I was thinking along the lines of `\w+{1,6}` but it also failed to do the required.

PS: Explanation of what the regular expression is doing will be appreciated.

Comment: How can one know when your movie name ends? The final delimiter is `.` or `-`, but the movie names themselves are delimited by both of these.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: you can see the pattern `moviename` followed by `delimiter` followed by `S07E23 or 313 or s02e07 or 3x13`. So you can pretty much say movieename will be followed by a pattern like `[S|s]?\d+[\.\_\_x]?[e|E]\d+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can detect if the .'s next token contains digit, if not, consider it as part of the name.

HOWEVER, I personally think there is no perfect solution for this. it'd still meet problem for something like:

```
24.313.480p.hdtv.x264-2hd.mkv            // 24
Warehouse.13.s02e07.hdtv.x264-xor.avi    // warehouse 13
```

Comment: @ronnie: try this ^[\.\D]+[\.\_\- ]. it should work with the full-character title

Comment: The character class `[-._ ]` removes those ugly backslashes. The Dot is not special inside a character class, as is nothing except `-`, `^` and backslashed alphabetic characters symbolizing other character classes.

Comment: In your regex is `\.` necessary before `\D`.

Comment: @ronnie, you're right. \D is enough, I was careless. by the way, could you accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

As StanleyZ said, you'll always get into trouble with names containing numbers.

But, if you take these special cases appart, you can try :

```
#perl

$\=$/;

map {

    if (/^([\w\.]+)[\.\_]([SE\d]+[\.\_].*)$/i) {
        print "Match : Name='$1'        Suffix='$2'";
    } else {
        print "Did not match $_";
    }
}
qw!
    Supernatural_S07E23_720p_HDTV_X264-DIMENSION.mkv
    the.listener.313.480p.hdtv.x264-2hd.mkv
    How.I.met.your.mother.s02e07.hdtv.x264-xor.avi
  !;
```

which outputs :

```
Match : Name='Supernatural'     Suffix='S07E23_720p_HDTV_X264-DIMENSION.mkv'
Match : Name='the.listener'     Suffix='313.480p.hdtv.x264-2hd.mkv'
Match : Name='How.I.met.your.mother'     Suffix='s02e07.hdtv.x264-xor.avi'
```

*note : aren't you doing something illegal ? ;)*

Comment: That's right, observe the pattern of the episode, make cases, convert it structural if you really need it.